# WPF Routing Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, events, routes

How to know whether it is in the chain of events other events after the current one?
(For example in child elements of the current UserControl)

I am inside the event handler :

```
private void UserControl_ContextMenuOpening(object sender,ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{

  //if no any next menus - show my last menu in chain
  ShowLastMenu(e);
   e.Handled = true;

}
```

And I want to display the context menu, but only in case if the queue is empty.